# buildozer "debug android debug"

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to convert my kivy project to APK using buildozer on ubuntu 18.04 and when i run "buildozer android debug"
every thing work well until i get the following warning

```
root@DESKTOP-P95MD4C:/home/hussam/app# buildozer  android debug
# Check configuration tokens
Buildozer is running as root!
This is not recommended, and may lead to problems later.
Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? y
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master dd69749f [origin/master] Merge pull request #1955 from kivy/release-2019.08.09
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 17c
# Android NDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,libffi --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 17c
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and requirements (python3, kivy, libffi)
[INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7...(and 22 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    hostpython3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading libffi
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/libffi/libffi/archive/v3.2.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    libffi download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    openssl download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7...(and 21 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7...(and 21 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7...(and 19 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-amalgamation-3150100.zip
[INFO]:    sqlite3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading python3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/python3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/python3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    python3 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7...(and 21 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-40.9.0.zip
[INFO]:    setuptools download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/6553ad4.zip
[INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading android
[INFO]:    Skipping android download as no URL is set
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/1.11.1.zip
[INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop
[INFO]:    hostpython3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/libffi/libffi/archive/v3.2.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    libffi is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    openssl is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_image is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-amalgamation-3150100.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    sqlite3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    python3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-40.9.0.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    setuptools is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/six-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    six is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/6553ad4.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    pyjnius is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    -> running rm -rf /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/...(and 74 more)
[INFO]:    -> running cp -a /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/...(and 174 more)
[INFO]:    Unpacking kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/1.11.1.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    kivy is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libffi has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for libffi[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    libffi already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    openssl has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_image has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_image[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_image already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_mixer[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sqlite3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    python3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for python3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    python3 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    setuptools has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    six has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    pyjnius already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding android for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    android has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    # Building recipes
[INFO]:    Building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Skipping hostpython3 (3.7.1) build, as it has already been completed
[INFO]:    Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libffi said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    openssl said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Building sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Building sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Building sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sqlite3 said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build
[WARNING]: Doing some hacky stuff to link properly
[INFO]:    -> running cp /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/platforms/androi...(and 38 more)
[INFO]:    -> running cp /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/platforms/androi...(and 36 more)
[WARNING]: lld not found, linking without it. Consider installing lld if linker errors occur.
[INFO]:    Activating flags for sqlite3
[INFO]:    Activating flags for libffi
[INFO]:    Activating flags for openssl
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Building setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    setuptools apparently isn't already in site-packages
[INFO]:    Installing setuptools into site-packages
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running python setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android...(and 71 more)
Exception in thread background thread for pid 1306:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 844, in build_arch
    self.install_python_package(arch)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 863, in install_python_package
    _env=hpenv, *self.setup_extra_args)
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,libffi --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/hussam/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

and this's what i try to do :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

but the error not fixed
please any one know the problem tell my what's it and how to fix it with sample step and details thanks

Comment: Make sure you have the libffi-dev package installed.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: the above lines shows to to me when i run sudo apt-get install -y libffi-dev it looks like that's the package is installed so can give me any other solution please

Comment: 1.  install libffi-dev
2.  buildozer -v android clean
3.  buildozer -v android debug // and the problem solved